# Excel VB searching script

Tags: vb.net, excel, search, basic, vba

I am trying to write a script in Visual Basic, which can do this:
I have 2 Excel sheet and I want to search all  row from on by one from #1 excel sheet in #2 excel sheet, and if it is similar I want to replace a specific column in that row(in the #2 excel sheet).

The problem is, that I don't know how to search in an Excel document in VB and then working with the searching result.

An example:

```
#1 Excel sheet

   A      B   C
Ferrari|1997|5.0|
Porsche|1998|7.0|

#2 Excel Sheet

   A      B   C
Audi   |1993|4.0|
Ferrari|1997|2.0|
Porsche|1998|3.0|
Opel   |1999|1.4|
```

So in that case I want to replace in #2 Excel Shhet the Ferrari and Porsche row from #1 Excel Sheet and replace the "C" column with the new value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So... you want to hire a programmer?

Comment: No, I just want to know, that is it even poosible to do in VB?

Comment: It is possible, a programmer can read the cells from both document with a macro and then compare them and replace

Comment: Can u give me a sample code? Im not familiar with VB yet, only beginner level.

Comment: Do you use an editor (IDE) or do you program vb with help from excel macros?

Comment: I don't use IDE. I'm using built in VB editor in Excel.

I would really appreciate if anybody could help me, I don't need that somebody write to me the whole code, just an example or how to descrition.

Comment: Anybody can help maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to left outer join on two tables. I typically do this using SQL in Excel.
Install my SQL Add-in for Excel: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-sql-add-in-run-sql-in-excel-with-ease/

Assuming you have one worksheet where in Sheet1 one you have

```
A   B   C
Ferrari 1   2
Porsche 2   3
Opel    3   10
Audi    4   11
```

and in another worksheet Sheet2 you have

```
A   B   C
Ferrari 1   20
Porsche 2   21
```

Open the "Run SQL" command from "Add-Ins"->"Run SQL". In "Output range" select any cell. In SQL type:

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, Iif(T2.C IS NULL,T1.C,T2.C) As C FROM [Sheet1$] As T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sheet2$] AS T2 ON T1.A = T2.A
```

Click "Run SQL" and that is it!

Comment: Thank you, but I can't install anything on the computer, only VB is available. This can't be done with VB?

Comment: The file is a vba add-in and does not req admin. Simply open it in excel

Comment: When I download the file it says only this:
/share/MD0_DATA/Web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/download-manager/cache/ must have to be writable!

What to do now?

Comment: Sorry - fixed it. Try again

Answer (score 0):

this code is neither good or pretty but it will work

```
Sub test()
Dim car As String
Dim car_year As String
Dim i As Integer
'read the first document and store it in an array(list)
i = 1
car = Range("A" & i).Value
car_year = Range("B" & i).Value
While car <> ""
MsgBox car & "-" & car_year
'check if the combination car+car_year exist the the first document and replace cell C(i)
i = i + 1
car_year = Range("B" & i).Value
car = Range("A" & i).Value
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. As I reading the code, it doesn't do what you did write in the comment.

Comment: I don't see that part where it switch between sheets, also I don't understand the arraylist part.
It just read one value in the variable, but doesn't iterate through it.